# onLoad event of <img /> tag does't fire on initial page access

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-chrome, safari

Consider following component

```
import React from 'react';

function Image() {
  function onLoad() {
    console.log("Loaded...")
  }

  return (
      <img
        src="http://..."
        onLoad={onLoad}
        decoding="async"
      />
  );
}

export default Image;
```

For some reason `onLoad` event isn't firing consistently i.e. when I initially load the page and refresh it it is not triggered, but when I mount component interactively in react i.e without page load it is triggered.

I played around with removing `decoding="async"` and adding `onError` handler to see if those gave more info, but behaviour didn't change.

I see this same behaviour on macOS safari and chrome browsers.

EDIT: In cases where it doesn't work image is not loaded at all

Comment: Does the image load without firing the onLoad event or does the image not load?

Comment: @anna not load at all

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I figured out how to make it work in my case. I guess onLoad event wasn't executing because image was already loaded, so I altered my code to the following and it works as expected now

```
import React, { useRef, useEffect } from 'react';

function Image() {
  const imgRef = useRef<HTMLImageElement>(null);

  function onLoad() {
    console.log("Loaded...")
  }

  useEffect(() => {
   if (imgRef.current?.complete) {
    onLoad();
   }
  }, []);

  return (
      <img
        ref={imgRef}
        src="http://..."
        onLoad={onLoad}
        decoding="async"
      />
  );
}

export default Image;
```

Comment: This is what I was searching for

Comment: Perfect. Not sure why JS doesn't get loaded before

Answer (score 0):

Can you provide more info about the error?
It should work, using an arrow function and calling it on the onLoad event of the img

```js
import React from 'react';


  onLoadFunction=()=>{
    console.log('just loaded');
  }
  return (
      <img
        src="http://..."
        onLoad={this.onLoadFunction}

      />
  );
}

export default Image;
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue might be that `Image` is a reserved keyboard in DOM, Consider Changing name of the function. Otherwise it might change the Image Class.

```js
// Image Size is >3MB
const App = () => {
  
  const onImageLoad = () => {
    console.log("Working...")
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <img src="https://unplash-api.herokuapp.com/api/Ri8c2qFg32A/full" onLoad={onImageLoad}/>
    </div>
  )
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"))
```

```css
img {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason is because the image is loaded even before React hydrates the page and starts listening to the image's `load` event. A more in-depth explanation can be found [on this GitHub issue](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/12641#issuecomment-382745656).

To solve this issue, @ilja's solution of checking if the image has already loaded via the `.complete` attribute in a `useEffect` works well.